# How to get comment votes using raw sql query?

Tags: 7, database, rating

In a D7 site, comments are voted using [rate](https://www.drupal.org/project/rate) module.

I'm wondering how to get the rating of all comments of 'story' content **using raw sql query**?

Comment: of all nodes of contenty type `story` or just particular one?

Comment: Ideally all of them. But even if I know how to make a query for one node, it should be easy to generalize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you are SQL to get the total vote count for widget type number for each comment od node type "story"

```
SELECT c.cid,count(v.vote_id) FROM votingapi_vote v JOIN comment c ON v.entity_id=c.cid JOIN node n ON n.nid=c.nid WHERE n.type='story' GROUP BY v.entity_id;
```

If you want to get the total numer of votes for all "story" nodes then:

```
SELECT c.cid,count(v.vote_id) FROM votingapi_vote v JOIN comment c ON v.entity_id=c.cid JOIN node n ON n.nid=c.nid WHERE n.type='story'
```

Or conditional for voting type like you did:

```
SELECT c.cid, count(v.value) FROM votingapi_vote v JOIN comment c ON v.entity_id=c.cid JOIN node n ON n.nid=c.nid WHERE n.type='story' and v.value_type='points' GROUP BY v.entity_id;
```

Comment: This is good hint, but what I want is the total value (not total number) of votes given to each comment, exactly as what users see on pages. When I run the above query it returns only one row while there are many comments.

Comment: I think count(vote value) = count(votes given) for comment, at least for vote type number

Comment: Well, this one worked for me:  `SELECT c.cid, count(v.value) FROM votingapi_vote v JOIN comment c ON v.entity_id=c.cid JOIN node n ON n.nid=c.nid WHERE n.type='story' and v.value_type='points'
GROUP BY v.entity_id;`  Please modify answer and I'll accept it. Thanks a lot.